# empty result when using a subquery select

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables (table1, table2) in a database (both with type InnoDB). They both have a column "article". In table1 "article" is the primary index, in table2 "article" is defined as "unique". Both of those columns have data type `varchar(32)`, also the same collation.

I am trying to get a list of all "article" values which are in table1, but NOT in table2.

table1 contains about 5000 rows, table2 contains about 3000 rows, so I should get at least 2000 "article" values as a result. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT article FROM table1
WHERE article NOT IN
(SELECT article FROM table2);
```

But this returns an empty result...

When I do it the other way around (i.e. select all "article"s from table2 which are not in table1), it works, that query returns around 700 values.

I suppose this must have to do with the different index/unique status of "article" in the two tables. But how can I modify the query to get it working?

Comment: My first instinct would be to see if the data types are a match inthe relevant columns.

Comment: I forgot to add that: Yes, both of those columns have data type `varchar(32)`, also the same collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join` instead. It is faster with many values anyway:

```
SELECT t1.article 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.article = t2.article
WHERE t2.article IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! There are definitely no NULL values in these columns, but your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a second solution myself (despite the accepted answer fully working): Apparently in this situation the subquery *requires*  a `WHERE` clause for the whole query to work. So I added a WHERE clause that will apply to *all* rows in `table2` (i.e. `WHERE article != ""`). So the complete (working) query now looks like this:

```
SELECT article FROM table1
WHERE article NOT IN
(SELECT article FROM table2 WHERE article != "");
```